# Leave white space at a specific portion of the page

Tags: spacing

I need to leave a portion of the page empty (3.5" from the top to 7" from the top), while using the rest of the page. Something is going to get printed over that portion of the page later. What would be an easy way to 'skip' that portion of the page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please ignore Community[Bot].  It's a bot that sometimes doesn't know what it's talking about.

Comment: Is this for a single, specific page? How big is the rest of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely more sophisticated solutions, but what I would do is add a `minipage` at the top of the page, and use `\vspace{3.5in}` to add the necessary whitespace.

Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t][2.5in][t]{\textwidth}
        % 2.5in should be replaced with 3.5in minus your top margin
        Do whatever here;
    \end{minipage}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} % THIS IS THE HORIZONTAL RULE AT 3.5 INCHES FROM TOP

    \vspace{3.5in}

    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} % THIS IS THE HORIZONTAL RULE AT 7 INCHES FROM TOP
    then begin here again, leaving 3.5--7 inches from the top of the page empty.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

where the space between the horizontal rules is the space that you need empty.